# "You just won the lottery? Chapeau!"

Tags: word-usage, loanwords

> "You just won the lottery? Chapeau!"

This is the first time I have seen such usage in English.

Literally 'Chapeau' means 'hat', but the intention (that I [get from the internet](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chapeau)) is something like 'My hat is off to you' or 'Hats off!' or 'Congratulations!' or 'Mad props!' or 'Good for you' or 'Cheers'.

The primary question is: What is the provenance of this in English.

And secondary questions: 
- at what point did it enter English? Is it direct to British English from across the channel? Or is it North American only, borrowed from French-Canadian? 
- And what is the feel of it? Is it mostly ironic (as 'good for you' often is)?
- Is there a difference in English usage between the French singular 'chapeau!' and the plural 'chapeaux!' (or is it meaningless distinction in English). I've seen both usages.

Comment: I personally have never encountered this usage.  Have you seen it frequently? Or at least more than occasionally?

Comment: @DanBron I've only seen it this once (first time! chapeau!). But [it was used in a public article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-happened-apple-design-jose-berengueres) so there's some expectation that the writer thought it common enough to be understandable. Also the urban dictionary entry confirms that other people (of dubious formality) have seen it. UD is not the OED but it _is_ evidence.

Comment: I think it is just a French expression which is fairly common in continental Europe but that has  actually never  entered common  usage in English. Any usage is related to people familiar with the expression!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a shortened version of French [*Je vous lève le chapeau*](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1436694) (I take my hat off to you), not English as such.

Comment: According to [this source in French](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/chapeau-bas-tirer-son-chapeau-chapeau.php), it is originated as a sign of respect or admiration in 17th century (in French culture). The source lists similar usages in other languages also. I'm not sure when the French form entered English (it might need an extensive analysis in Google Books). I haven't heard it in Canada. (but I'm not in Quebec)

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the expression is used in English, by English speakers who don’t necessarily know the French word or its meaning. That to me makes it an English-as-such word. It’s not in any dictionaries I can find, though, not even Wiktionary, which surprises me, because it’s not _that_ uncommon. (Judging by Mitch, Dan, and ermanen’s comments, it seems it might be just a UK/European/non-North American thing.)

Comment: @Janus: I speak passable French (I lived there for a year), but I'm not sure I've ever heard a native Anglophone use the term except facetiously or pretentiously. OED lists *chapeau* because of its specialised sense in heraldry, and *chapeau-bras* because there isn't really an English equivalent. But the usage under consideration here is effectively just "using a foreign word".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’ve mostly heard the exclamation used by teenagers who certainly did not know enough French (if any) to know it from there. Unlike most other obvious French loan words which come off as quite pretentious, _chapeau_ is, in my own personal experience, almost exclusively used in a very informal register, being almost slang-like. This is quite similar to _kudos_, whose status as an obvious Ancient Greek loan word might be expected to make it pretentious, but which is in reality very colloquial. (I’ve also seen teenagers write it _shappo_ and similar ways.)

Comment: @Janus: Perhaps we just interact with a different class of people. The usage obviously *is* essentially "French", and goes back a long way (here's an instance of ["Chapeau!" cried Peter](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=b_EOAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Chapeau+cried%22&dq=%22Chapeau+cried%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M1nvVIm8MKW17gaftYCQCA&redir_esc=y) from almost a century ago), and I think it's bordering on meaningless to ask when/if anyone has started using it as an "English" word without even realising where it came from or exactly what it meant in the original language.

Comment: The writer was trying to be "continental".  The expression is not at all common in US English, and most in the US would have to think a few seconds to comprehend what was meant.

Comment: Did this come in a spam message? It sounds like a great autocorrect or Google Translate flub which a non-native speaker wouldn't have caught,

Comment: @Rache No, it was very deliberate, has been seen elsewhere, and makes sense, so I don't think it was an autocorrect (nothing else works there) and it's not an eggcorn (same thing, nothing else works there).

Comment: Re French, see [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chapeau) i.e. _Tirer son chapeau. Chapeau bas ou absol. chapeau! Pour exprimer l'admiration_ (TLFi). "Tirer son chapeau" is 1585 according to Rey. Note if you add "à quelqu'un", then you're leaving. Most likely "lever son chapeau" is just a greeting, _to tip your hat_ or such.

Comment: I have since heard this in French French with exactly the same meaning, 'Hat's off!' so it is a confirmed pure loanword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earliest Google Books match for "Chapeau!" in the sense of "Hats off to you" (probably) is from Robert Lane Kauffmann, "[The Other in Question: Dialogical Experiments in Montaigne, Kafka, and Cortázar](https://books.google.com/books?id=hRdINzHk4ZAC&pg=PA191&dq=%22chapeau%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2vkQVdysL4eyogTE3oHoDg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCDhQ#v=onepage&q=%22chapeau%22&f=false)," in Tullio Maranhão, ed. *The Interpretation of Dialogue* (1990):

> *Jack* *[a fictional graduate student in comparative literature]:* It seems you've used  an outflanking maneuver against me. ***Chapeau***! To your echo of Wittgenstein's ladder analogy, I answer that I don't let go of the ladder. That is, I don't simply dismiss the texts I choose to comment on, but defend and espouse their critical and experimental aspects, using them against ideological or uncritical positions, whether in the same or in other texts.

This instance is something of an outlier, however, as the next-oldest Google Books matches are to a 2005 [restaurant guide's](https://books.google.com/books?id=_Ad9mcsWZbEC&pg=PT72&dq=%22chapeau%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FQURVZiVI830oATjqYGICQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBzgy#v=onepage&q=%22chapeau%22&f=false) mention of a San Francisco Bay Area bistro named Chapeau! that opened in 1996, and a use of "*Chapeau*!" in dialogue in an Annie Proulx short story called "[I've Always Loved This Place](https://books.google.com/books?id=VKsfowF1e5oC&pg=PA40&dq=%22chapeau%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AQIRVe-hN5PnoATQjILIDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBDhk#v=onepage&q=%22chapeau%22&f=false)," included in a 2008 collection of Proulx's stories called *Fine Just the Way It Was: Wyoming Stories 3*.

In any case, whether Robert Lane Kauffmann was simply ahead of his time, or whether comparative literature  professors are generally in touch with the pulse of the street and thus can be counted on to lead the literary pack in bringing up-to-date slang into serious published work, the 1990 occurrence in his lengthy article is easily the first in Google Books.

Comment: Nice research! Not surprising that it is so recent an addition.

Answer (score 6):

It's used jokingly in the British sporting world, perhaps especially in cycling, as an expression of admiration or respect. Possibly popularized by sports commentator David Duffield. See also http://m.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-23343625

Comment: Apparently, _Chapeau!_ is a brand for cycling apparel also. They also have [bicycle caps that say _Chapeau!_ on it!](http://www.chapeau.cc/chapeau-lightweight-cap-stripe-white-black-m-l-white-black-unisex-stripe.html) :)